# React dev tools profiler saying I'm on an old version

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, optimization, profiler, react-devtools

I am looking to optimise my React app and would like to use the profiler within the react dev tools Chrome extension.

I tried to use it and saw that it says:

[image]

which made sense as I was still on an older version of React at the time (16.1.4 I believe). So I have since upgraded a little to `^16.8.6` and built & deployed the changes to my environment, but for some reason I am still seeing the message indicating that I am on a pre-16.5 version... I'm not sure what is wrong.

Also, I have a local express server to build and render things locally, and that seems to have no issues whatsoever, and will let me use the profiler...

Is there something in my build that is keeping it on an old version perhaps?